# Overloading with a template function

Tags: c++, function, templates

I'm having trouble identifying the problem here as I'm using multiple techniques I am not that familiar with (splitting code into files, templates), so I have recreated it in the simplest way I could think:

classes.h:

```
class baseClass{
public:
    virtual void myfunction(double dA, double dB) = 0; //Pure virtual function
    virtual void myfunction(double dC) = 0;//Overloaded pure virtual function
};

class derivedClass1 :baseClass{
public:
    void myfunction(double dA, double dB)override;
    void myfunction(double dC)override;
};

class derivedClass2 :baseClass{
public:
    void myfunction(double dA, double dB)override;
    void myfunction(double dC)override;
};
```

classes.cpp :

```
#include"classes.h"

void derivedClass1::myfunction(double dA, double dB){
    //DO STUFF
}

void derivedClass2::myfunction(double dA, double dB){
    //Do different stuff to derivedClass1
}

template <class type>
void type::myfunction(double dC){
    double dA = dC;
    double dB = 0; //In place of a complex calculation

    myfunction(dA, dB)  //Call the function for the
//relevant class and 2 input arguments.

}
```

main:

```
#include"classes.h"

int main(){
    derivedClass1 example;
    example.myfunction(1.0);
}
```

What I want to do is overload all myfunction for only one input argument with a template function. As there's many derived classes I wanted to use templates. However, when I do something like this I get this error:

> error C2063: 'myfunction' : not a function

Is there an easy way to do this or a better way around it? I've tried putting the template in the header file and removing the in class declarations but that doesn't work either.

Comment: You cannot use templates like this. Perhaps you should read up on templates before trying them again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need templates at all. Polymorphism will solve this problem for you. Would this work for you:

```
class baseClass{
public:
    virtual void myfunction(double dA, double dB) = 0; //Pure virtual function
    virtual void myfunction(double dC) {
      double dA = dC;
      double dB = 0;

      myfunction(dA, dB)  // Calls the function of the derived class
    }
};
```

Then your main function can look like:

```
#include"classes.h"

int main(){

    derivedClass1 example;
    baseClass *caller = &example;    
    caller.myfunction(1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    I think you want to write general function outside any class to call the respective class function.

    1) You don't need to put type::myfunction
        template <class type> 
        void myfunction(baseClass *caller, double dc) 
        {
            double dA = dC;
            double dB = 0; //In place of a complex calculation
            caller->myfunction(double dA, double dB)  //Call the function for the
        }
    2) actually, you don't need type template for it if there are not multiple data types
       void myfunction(baseClass *caller,double dc)
       {
            double dA = dC;
            double dB = 0; //In place of a complex calculation
            caller->myfunction(double dA, double dB)  //Call the function for the
       }


int main(){
    derivedClass1 example;
    myfunction(&example,1.0);
    derivedClass2 example2;
    myfunction(&example2,2.0);
    baseClass example3;
    myfunction(&example3,4.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there lot of problems in the above code you provided like the following

```
void type::myfunction(double dC)
```

In this above statement "type" should be the class name in which myfunction will be member. Instead you given this as a template type.

I am rewritten your code as follows,

```
class baseClass
{
  public:
    template<typename Type>
    void myfunction(Type dA, double dB)
    {};

    template<typename Type>
    void myfunction(Type dC)
    {};
};

class derivedClass1 :baseClass
{
  public:

   template<typename Type>
   void myfunction(Type dA, double dB)
   {
     //DO STUFF
   }


   template<typename Type>
   void myfunction(Type dC)
   {
      Type dA = dC;
      double dB = 0; //In place of a complex calculation

      myfunction(dA, dB);
   };
};

class derivedClass2 :baseClass
{
  public:

  template<typename Type>
  void myfunction(Type dA, double dB)
  {
    //Do different stuff to derivedClass1
  }

  template<typename Type>
  void myfunction(Type dC)
  {
     Type dA = dC;
    double dB = 0; //In place of a complex calculation

    myfunction(dA, dB);
  };
};

int main()
{
  derivedClass1 example;
  example.myfunction(1.0);
}
```